# 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite, pug

I'm getting started in Node.js and I'm completely confused as to why I can't get the results of my SQL query to render on a page, i'm using sqlite3.
This is a part of my index.js file

```
router.get('/students', function (req, res, module) {

var fs = require("fs");
var file = "./test.db";
var exists = fs.existsSync(file);
if (!exists) {
    console.log("Creating DB file.");
    fs.openSync(file, "w");
}

var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);

db.serialize(function () {
    if (!exists) {
        db.run("Create table students ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, Nom varchar (255), Prenom varchar (255) );");
    }
});
    db.all('SELECT * FROM students', function selectCb(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        for (var i in rows) {
            console.log(rows[i]);
        }
        res.render('showResults.jade', {
            results: rows
        });
});
db.close();
res.render('students', { title: 'list' });
});
```

This is my Jade (create.jade) file;

```
    block content
form(method='get', action='/students/create')
    button(type='submit') Creer
ul
    each item, i in results
        li #{item.Nom} (#{item.Prenom})
        li= JSON.stringify(item)
```

I put all of this things in my express app, I launch it with my shell, I receive all the sql data like this:

```
{ ID: 1, Nom: 'zeze', Prenom: 'zeze' }
{ ID: 2, Nom: 'ertty', Prenom: 'uuuuuuuuuuu' }
```

But my /students page show a message

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ormUG.png

Could you please help me, I'm really desperate.
(Sorry for my bad english I'm French) ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
res.render('students', { title: 'list' });
```

and this line

```
each item, i in results
```

The variable names do not match.

From the picture, I can see that you are rendering the page called `students.jade`. For that page, you are sending variable `title` to Jade but you declared that the variable would be called `results` in Jade.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the second `res.render` call?

It is possible that it is the one being called instead of the first one since the async call to the DB is not yet finished when the execution reaches the second `res.render` call.

Answer (score -3):

db.close() should be moved inside the query's callback because it closes the db connection before the query has the chance to finish.  Here is the revised code:

```
 db.all('SELECT * FROM students', function selectCb(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        db.close();       // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        throw err;
    }
    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log(rows[i]);
    }
    res.render('showResults.jade', {
        results: rows
    });
    db.close();   // <<<<<<<<<<
});
```